# h:dataTable has no value

Tags: java, jsf

HI,
Have used JSF h:data Table - the jsf datatable is coming empty, my sp is returning values hence getList returns values but only headers are seen in the browser, table values are not seen in the browser.

**Following is my JSP**

```
    <h:panelGrid>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Employee Details" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:dataTable value="#{dataTableBean.list}" var="loc"
            bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3"
            first="0" rows="5" width="50%">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Sponsor ID" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{loc.sponsorID}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Sponsor Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{loc.sponsorName}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Distributor ID" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{loc.distributorID}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Distributor Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{loc.distributorName}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**MY Bean**

public class DataTableBean {

```
private List<BillTransPay> list;

public List<BillTransPay> getList() {
    String SP_BILLPAY = "{call sp_aw_BillTransPay(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    con = java.sql.DriverManager
                .getConnection(conString);
        CallableStatement cbls = con
                .prepareCall("{call sp_aw_BillTransPay(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        cbls.setString(1, "csf");
        cbls.setString(2, "20100101");
        cbls.setString(3, "20100301");
        cbls.setString(4, "B");
        cbls.setString(5, "01CS");
        cbls.setString(6, "ALL");
        cbls.setInt(7, 14000);
        rs = cbls.executeQuery();
        list = new ArrayList<BillTransPay>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            BillTransPay btp = new BillTransPay();
            btp.setSponsorID(rs.getString("SponsorCode"));
            btp.setSponsorName(rs.getString("SponsorName"));
            btp.setDistributorID(rs.getString("DistID"));
            btp.setDistributorName(rs.getString("DistName"));
            list.add(btp);

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<BillTransPay> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

}

**Faces-Config.xml**

```
    **<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>dataTableBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.SQLProcess.dto.DataTableBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>**
```

Comment: Code seems ok. what you get as HTML ? are you really passing something using `List` ?

Comment: only the headers, but sp is returning value.

Comment: Try with `getList` on XHTML or say `retrieveData` and refactor method name

Comment: if i try getList - i get the following error                        javax.servlet.ServletException: /JSP/dataTableDemo.jsp(15,3) '#{dataTableBean.getList}' Property 'getList' not found on type com.SQLProcess.dto.DataTableBean
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:256)

Comment: I would try to remove the data aquisition out of the getter method (put it in the constructor since it is a request scoped bean). Let the getter only return the list filled by the constructor.

Comment: @Matt good point, I missed that is `value` attr.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a debugger or add a `System.out.println(list);` right before `return list;` to see if the method get called and the list *really* contains items.

Said that, this expensive DB job should really not be done in a **getter**. It can be called multiple times during a request. You don't want to unnecessarily hit/stress your DB. Move the DB job into the bean's constructor. Also, you're leaking DB resources by not explicitly closing the `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet`. You need to close them in `finally` block of the same `try` as where you have acquired them.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, there was a problem wid the sqldriver version - and din know why I din get any error , wen the page is accessed. but once coreect driver is placed the error is gone. Thank you all :D